# How to get Categories, items and subitems in Codeigniter 3 Model?

Tags: database, codeigniter, categories

I have just started building a webapp in Codeigniter and i can't solve a problem with nested queries in my model.

I have three Tables:

Categories, Links and Topics. Every Link and every Topic can have just one Category, whereas every Category can have multiple Links or Topics.

Every Link can have one Topic (or no Topic at all) and every Topic can have one or more Links.

The Table-Structure looks like this (shortened):

```
Categories:

 - ID
 - DESCR

Links:

- ID
- DESCR
- ID_CATEGORY
- ID_TOPIC (either an ID from the Topics-Table or NULL)

Topics:

- ID
- DESCR
- ID_CATEGORY

In my View, i want to display them in the following manner:

- Category 1
 - Link 1
 - Link 2
 - Topic 1
     - Topiclink 1
     - Topiclink 2
 - Link 3

- Category 2
 - Topic 2
     - Topiclink 3
     - Topiclink 4
 - Topic 3
     - Topiclink 5
     - Topiclink 6
 - Link 4
```

So there will be 3 nested queries.

My Model looks like this:

```
public function get_categories(){

    //1. Get the categories

    $this->db->select("                   
    ec.ID_CATEGORY, 
    c.DESCR,
    c.VISIBLE,
    i.KEYVALUE");
    $this->db->from("episode_categories ec");
    $this->db->join("categories c", "c.ID = ec.ID_CATEGORY");
    $this->db->join("ini i", "i.SETTING = c.VISIBLE");
    $this->db->where("i.KEYWORD", "CATEGORY_VISIBLE");
    $this->db->where("ec.ID_EPISODE", $_SESSION['cur_episode']);
    $categories = $this->db->get()->result_array();  

    //2. Get the Entries (Topics and Links with NULL as TOPIC_ID)

    foreach($categories as $key => $value)
    {
        $sql_links="SELECT 
        pf_users.USERNAME,
        pf_users.NAME_SHOW,
        pf_links.ID AS ID,
        pf_links.URL AS URL,
        pf_links.ID_USER AS ID_USER,
        pf_links.ID_EPISODE,
        pf_links.ID_CATEGORY,
        pf_links.DESCR,
        NULL AS IS_TOPIC,
        pf_links.REIHENF,
        pf_links.DONE,
        pf_links.DONE_TS,
        pf_links.INFO AS INFO,
        pf_episoden.DONE AS EPISODE_DONE 

        from pf_links 
        JOIN pf_users on pf_users.ID = pf_links.ID_USER 
        JOIN pf_episoden on pf_episoden.ID = pf_links.ID_EPISODE 

        WHERE ID_EPISODE = ".$_SESSION['cur_episode']." AND ID_CATEGORY = ".$value['ID_CATEGORY']." AND ID_TOPIC IS NULL 

        UNION ALL SELECT pf_users.USERNAME,

        pf_users.NAME_SHOW,
        pf_topics.ID AS ID,
        NULL AS URL,
        pf_topics.ID_USER AS ID_USER,
        pf_topics.ID_EPISODE,
        pf_topics.ID_CATEGORY,
        pf_topics.DESCR,
        1 AS IS_TOPIC,
        pf_topics.REIHENF,
        pf_topics.DONE,
        pf_topics.DONE_TS,
        pf_topics.INFO AS INFO,
        pf_episoden.DONE AS EPISODE_DONE 
        from pf_topics 
        JOIN pf_users on pf_users.ID = pf_topics.ID_USER 
        JOIN pf_episoden on pf_episoden.ID = pf_topics.ID_EPISODE 
        WHERE ID_EPISODE = ".$_SESSION['cur_episode']." AND ID_CATEGORY = ".$value['ID_CATEGORY']." ORDER BY REIHENF,
        ID ASC";
        $query_links = $this->db->query($sql_links);
        $categories[$key]['link_list'] = $query_links->result_array(); 

         //3. Get the Topiclinks (Links with an ID_TOPIC set)

         foreach( $categories[$key]['link_list'] as $key2 => $value2)
         {
              if($value2['IS_TOPIC'] == 1)
              {
                   $sql_topic_links = "SELECT * FROM pf_links WHERE ID_TOPIC = ".$value2['ID'];
                   $query_topic_links = $this->db->query($sql_topic_links);
                   $categories[$key2]['topic_links'] = $query_topic_links->result();                            
              }
         }
    }
    return $categories;
}
```

Everything works fine until the links of the topics (So Step 3 in the Code). The array i get is the same for every topiclink with the last one of the possible ID_TOPIC. So the links within the topics are all the same.

What do i have to change to get just the links for the specific topics in the third step of the function?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue:

In Step 3 the following line

```
$categories[$key2]['topic_links'] = $query_topic_links->result();
```

must be changed to:

```
 $categories[$key]['link_list'][$key2]['topic_links'] = $query_topic_links->result_array();
```

So in my view i can iterate trhough the result-sets.